# Scrapy init returns a None

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-pipeline

I have a scrapy scrawling script.

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'quotes'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.cat = [kwargs.get('cat')] 
    print(self.cat)

def start_requests(self):
    #print(self.params)
    urls = ['https://google.com/html/?q=a%v%c']
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

On command line:

```
scrapy crawl quotes -a cat="avc"
```

When I run the command:

It prints "None"

How can I access the value "avc" passed through the command line in the program

Answer (score 0):

There are things missing in your code. Check out the below sample code

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cat = kwargs.get('cat')
        print(self.cat)

    def start_requests(self):
        # print(self.params)
        urls = [f"https://www.google.com/search?q={self.cat}"]
        # urls = ['https://google.com/html/?q=a%v%c']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response, "Response <---")
```

The requested google URL was wrong, I have changed it with the new one.

```
<200 https://www.google.com/search?q=avc> Response <---
```